# SQL Sorting with Two Joined Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables

```
people
============
id, name
```

and

```
answer_sheets
============
id, person_id, answer, date_answered
```

- `person_id` is a foreign key from people.id

Now, what I wanted to do is to sort `people` in such in order basing it on the latest `answer_sheets.date_answered` (we can derive that one `people` row can have many `answer_sheets` rows)

Say for example we have the tables

```
people  
============
id  name  
1   Person1  
2   Person2  
3   Person3  
4   Person4  
5   Person5  


answer_sheets  
=============
id  person_id   answer  date_answered  
1   1           string  JUN 13  
2   2           string  JUN 15  
3   3           string  JUN 17  
4   2           string  JUN 18  
5   1           string  JUN 19  
6   3           string  JUN 20  
7   2           string  JUN 25
```

and I wanted to order `people` in `ASC` order based on a `people` row's `answer_sheets.date_answered`

the output must be

```
=============
id  name      last_date_answered
4   Person4   NIL
5   Person5   NIL
1   Person1   JUN 19
3   Person3   JUN 20
2   Person2   JUN 25
```

You can observe that `people` with `id`s 4 and 5 does not have an `answer_sheet` and yet they should be included in the list.
Question: What must be the appropriate SQL query for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get records to display even if there is no match, you can use a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, MAX(a.date_answered)
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN answer_sheets a on p.id = a.personID
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
ORDER BY MAX(date_answered) ASC
```

And, if you want to try it out, or play with it more, I made a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6c70/11)...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  people.id,
  people.name,
  baseview.last_date_answered
FROM (
  SELECT
    person_id,
    MAX(date_answered) AS last_date_answered
  FROM answer_sheets
  ORDER BY IFNULL(MAX(date_answered),'0001-01-01')
  ) AS baseview
  INNER JOIN people ON bseview.person_id=people.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    people
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    MAX(date_answered) MaxDate
                      FROM      answer_sheets
                      WHERE     answer_sheets.PersonID = people.ID
                    ) L
```